# Normalize Object on Seaborn Scatter Plot

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn

I'm trying to get a grasp of the definition of the `hue_norm` param in [`seaborn.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html). I'm clear that you can pass a tuple to it to set the range you want but not the Normalize object it's referring to. I tried looking at their API docs to see if there's a definition for it but no dice.

Can anyone show an example of that `hue_norm` param with a Normalize object? Appreciate your guidance on it.

Comment: `hue_order` has nothing to do with "a Normalize object". It's a tuple/list that determines which category comes first, second, etc. E.g. if you have categories `A, C, B, A, A, B, B, A`, you could set `hue_order=["A", "B", "C"]` to have them appear in that order.

Comment: My bad, I was referring to `hue_norm`. Updating it now. Cheers!

Comment: I see. You can use one of the matplotlib normalization seen in [matplotlib.colors](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/colors_api.html), like `Normalize`, `PowerNorm` or `LogNorm`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll have a play then with these, but I would take your response as an answer already. :)